# Increase number of shown related products in the administration (Magento 2)

Tags: magento2, php, adminhtml, grid

When you **edit a product** in the magento **administration** the number of items listed in the **related products, up-sells and cross-sells** list is limited to 20. Also there is no possibility to change this like in felt every other grid.

I tried to fix this programmatically by creating an observer which sets the default limit to 50. The observer is called correctly (when adminhtml_block_html_before is fired) but nothing changes.

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I could fix this.

If you're interested:

create a new file

> app/code/$yourModule/Catalog/etc/adminhtml/di.xml

with the following content

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Initialization\Helper\HandlerInterface" type="Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Initialization\Helper\Plugin\Handler\Composite" />
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Locator\LocatorInterface" type="Magento\Catalog\Model\Locator\RegistryLocator"/>
<virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Pool" type="Magento\Ui\DataProvider\Modifier\Pool">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="modifiers" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="related" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">$yourModule\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Related</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">110</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

and copy from vendor the `Related.php` to

> /app/code/$yourModule/Catalog/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/Related.php

and add the `pageSize` to the `config` Array in the method `getGrid`.